# Limit solved by definite integral (Demidovich)

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I was solving this limit from the Demidovich's book of exercises:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{\vphantom{\Large a}\, n!\,}}{n}$$

and I managed to get it to this state but then I got stuck:

$$e^{\frac{1}{n}(\log(n) + \log(n - 1) + ... + \log(1)) - \log(n)}$$

where $\log x$ is a natural logarithm of x. Can you please provide any hint?

Comment: I just moved the $\color{#f00}{!}$ into de $\color{#f00}{\sqrt{\mbox{}}}$ umbrella which was not quite clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the ratio test to the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ given by:
$$ a_n = \frac{n!}{n^n}. $$
We have:

$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n} $$
hence $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1}{e}$ implies $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac{1}{e}$, no integrals needed.

---

If you want to use an integral at all costs, notice that:
$$ \log(a_n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) $$
hence, by Riemann sums:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\log(a_n)}{n} = \int_{0}^{1}\log(x)\,dx = \color{red}{-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I was so eagerly trying to construct an integral that I overlooked an easier solution. But let's say I want to solve it by constructing definite integral. Is there such a solution?

Comment: @Gogis: yes, just added.

Comment: Ok, just one thing: where did the n by which you divided the logarithm in the final equation come from?

Comment: @Gogis: $$\exp\frac{\log a_n}{n} = \sqrt[n]{a_n}$$ is our target.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's because you took $a_n$ as n-th power. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a brute force approach.

$$\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=e^{\frac1n \log(n!)-\log(n)}$$

Now, note that the term $\log(n!)$ can be written as

$$\begin{align}
\log(n!)&=\sum_{k=1}^n \log(k)\\\\
&=n\left(\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n\log(k/n)+\log(n)\right) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Note that the sum in $(1)$ is the Riemann sum for the logarithm function.  Therefore,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n\log(k/n)\right)
=\int_0^1 \log(x)\,dx=-1 \tag 2$$

From $(2)$ we have

$$\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n\log(k/n)=-1+\epsilon(n)$$

where $\lim_{n\to \infty}\epsilon(n)=0$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}&=e^{\frac1n \log(n!)-\log(n)}=e^{-1+\epsilon(n)}\\\\
&\to e^{-1}\,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to \infty
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why are you adding the $\log(n)$ in $(1)$ when we are subtracting it in the first equation?

Comment: Ok, I assume it's just a typo.

Comment: Or is it a part of the sum? It's not really clear to me.

Comment: @Gogis It's not a typo. We have $$\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)=n\log(n)+\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k/n)$$

Comment: Yes, my bad, now I understand.

Comment: @Gogis No worry.  Pleased to hear that all is OK now.  Well done!  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
You can use the **Stirling Asymptotic Expression** for 'large' $n$:
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\root[n]{n!} \over n}} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{\root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n}}^{1/n} \over n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\pars{2\pi}^{1/\pars{2n}}n^{1/\pars{2n}}\expo{-1}}
= \color{#f00}{{1 \over \expo{}}} \approx 0.3679
\end{align}

---

Note that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\ln\pars{n} \over 2n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\ln\pars{n + 1} - \ln\pars{n} \over \pars{2n + 2} - 2n} = 0
\quad\imp\quad\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{1/\pars{2n}} = 1
$$